# Screen flashes during "alpha" operations with integrated Intel 4500MHD GPU

Tags: graphic-drivers

Lenovo Thinkpad T500
Elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya

This machine has switchable graphics.  When I use the "discreet"  Mobility Radeon HD 3650 GPU there are no problems with the video, but when I use the "integrated" Intel 4500MHD, the screen will flash or flicker, and momentarily present a sort of "shattered" image when something on the screen transitions through being translucent.

The most frequent time this happens is when a notification box appears, but it also happens during log-in as the desktop fades-in.

I'd just leave it in Radeon mode all the time, but it's brutal on battery life, and generates a lot of heat too.

I'm wondering if there is a specific driver I need to load for the Intel graphics vs. the one that was installed by default?

Comment: Seems to be something with the drivers for these outdated and slow integrated GPUs.I had this same problem on a laptop with Intel X3100 (which is quite slow but good enough for normal tasks) and I could fix it by doing the following https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4617/application-windows-are-flickering-when-moving-closing-and-opening