# Application Windows are flickering when moving , closing and opening

Tags: graphic-drivers, window-management, intel, vaio

When moving , closing and opening a window it flickers with black lines.The computer is a SONY VAIO VGN-NR120E and has no problems in Windows 10 and has been like this from day one though it does not occur in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.No hardware upgrades except RAM , WiFi and Disk

Any help?

Comment: Do you have an Intel graphic card?

Comment: @FabioAntunes Yes, it is an Intel GMA X3100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have the same issue, random flickering then after a search I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1435861). Try doing this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
echo -e 'Section "Device"\n Identifier "Intel Graphics"\n Driver "Intel"\n Option "AccelMethod" "sna"\n Option "TearFree" "true"\nEndSection' | sudo tee /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
sudo reboot
```

Credits goes to [Guy Van Sanden](https://launchpad.net/~gvs) who saw this solution on Reddit.

Comment: I will try this